# SimpleDateFormat seems to allow a year of yy when the format is set to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: java, simpledateformat

If I have this:

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
formatter.setLenient(false);
formatter.parse("01/01/98");
```

Should my application throw an exception if a 2 digit year is passed in? It doesn't seem to have any issue with this.

Comment: Have you read the documentation or at the minimum examined the results of your code? What the parser does is completely correct and especially it is what it is expected to do. You're asking it to parse the 98th year since year 0 (not the 1998th year) and it does exactly that.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html): For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D.

Comment: Well, your application shouldn't use `SimpleDateFormat` at all. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead. In your case, `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDate`.

Comment: Consider spending some time and learning the new date stuff (it is in the java.time package).  The old stuff (that you are using) was terrible when it was first written and has been replaced by something that is not terrible (the java.time package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  `SimpleDateFormat` is used for both parsing a Date from a String and generating a String from a Date.  The interpretation of the format String varies between these usages.  In your case, you are parsing a Date from a String.   The `98` is a legitimate value and is interpreted literally (i.e. 98 AD) because you are using `yyyy`.  If you replace the `yyyy` with `yy` or `y` then the parsing should interpret the 98 as 1998.  If you want require 4-digit dates then you will need to add some verification code to do that.

Note that `setLenient` doesn't affect anything here because the values in each position are legitimate.  You are not required to have 4 digits in the year position (nor are you limited to 4 digits).  If the interpretation is not-lenient and you pass it "1998/04/12" it will throw an exception because 1998 is not in the range of 1-12.  If you set lenient then it will mod the value to get it into range (1998 becomes 6) and charge forward.  Since the year has no real bounds it has no effect on the year position.